# typescript type infer with settings

Tags: typescript, dynamic, types, type-inference, inferred-type

In the follow example, `getValue function` can not get the correct type.
Is there any way to infer type by configurable settings?
[Example Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/zh/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNH0B2YAtggFzQQAuSAlngOYDcWWu0wA9npUgK7AXskACgLEy3WnQCUaFq1wUAFtQgA6UQmgBefEQRNsuAL5YTmLKEgwAIuzqzDODeKqSDcnBy5U+A4c-JXehkMR3klFXU9bV1iA1YzMwtwKGgAYTAKB1YAiXp3MK9uX0ERPRcaYOz5HAi1DRiNeONTZkwirMQKCkkYHQBtDzRoAGsEAE8yAHIwKYAaaAA3MBAeUmgpvLop6CM5odRRiemAI3mllbWyAEYAJgBmXf2ww7HJjeBz5dX1n009g5Hd5TAAmdi+l3WtnsAJeQOmwEyEJ+ZAyWVhrFex2g0IW3yu6UyT0Bb1RmTxkLI0OJcNJcEQSApKPpyBpAF02hRxgAHTRpTjFfiCAA8ABUYmA8OMAHyNBAAd2gQlUKrASDoEDIkvG-TZMi0stFBSwAHoAFQWy1W62WigISjQABiYCFSHGNo91pNWAAZjw8PxqJwnS6-OMxdKhBQ1XQEBRUQKfK6I1IyOLQjgkHGeEg8PgFdBo+q40IpnbKABaDRTKQGIwGDrQMF0a4xZ2u8ZCaG16Amk3QahZeWCEYwE48LJ4dhZLw+6h0HNgE4gTQncbkOM9egQCyJtiZVs6dthoRo2u77zQHgMw8hjtCeDIc-mTDmz3v8tZWMUABqkOg8qDoo0AAAaQNAooge+77epgfoBj0wbfn+PzXEIdLaiEQyNoOCCEDEXRbhqqhzngIJCOwJwAFbaLKlFUaobzaFoOhvM+rDUD6Sq4YQWFhKwjaHPi-wxDxQwcVxUY8gg7BccJzE6FM8GBpwNbVDUrBZhQOZ5ngBbCaWn4XD8NbNDURjQAgICIOpGmZtmubGWsZnyGYCSWdZmgZhpShIOwip6YqACiSB+cIUxTlkPrsP6IKmUMiRtI2za3DEyGQmhoLgj2faFtJA54D6rKRWwghZvwF4OoiFCpTo6WoaW1VqeBaIML2-bXpoLVEgI0DftANB0IoWRcryBXRZVWSdUgtV9XGKFrGhj5IDI4HLW1bSmtBnpGfVaypYBSigewizICA7BgCCUHbTasHKYheZ7QgtwRuh2L8t4vDJqK0qphBBj3UGj3zZCL0-W97xbH9Rq+v6KnA7+oOvRhUrQ7ZOF2vhOiEb0JG0OR9G0dA9GMRMClAuxuCcdxmN8XZglOSJOhifxVOSaNMlyf+LGKYDql03ZuBaTp+aKgZZb2lkwnNTAMOszgFlWTZ3mCwNDl5vJ4Fy3ZbnGB5yviQoih+QFBYhWFpYldFsXxWEiUvsldhpSDPwvdCkZZdsz6NtVzuI67wpoh7TXe3u01+wtz0Pgyz5AA)

For example

```
class User {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Dog {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Cat {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const settings = [
    { key: 'a', value: 'string' },
    { key: 'b', value: 123 },
    { key: 'c', value: true },
    { key: 'dog', value: Dog },
    { key: 'cat', value: Cat },
    { key: Dog, value: Cat },
    { key: Cat, value: Dog },
    { key: User, value: User },
]

function getValue(key: any) {
    const item = settings.find(obj => obj.key === key);
    if (item) {
        const { value } = item
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            return new value('test value');
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('not found');
    }
}
```

Of course, I can use `as Dog` to force cast type.
`const dog = getValue('dog') as Dog;`
But I think it is a bit redundant.
Is there any better way to solve this problem?

---edit 2020-10-20---
In fact, the `settings` is not pre-defined.
It could be modified in the runtime.

Finally I want to implement a function like angular dependency injection function.
The `settings's` structure is like this:

```
[
{provide: User, useValue: new User('Tom')},
{provide: Cat, useClass: Cat},
{provide: Dog, useClass: Dog},
{provide: AnotherDog, useExiting: Dog},
{provide: AnotherCat, useFactory: function(user) { return user.cat; }, deps: [User]},
]
```

And the `settings` is not pre-defined. It could be modified in the runtime.

eg.

```
let settings = [
    { key: Cat, value: Cat },
    { key: Dog, value: Dog },
]
const cat1 = getValue(Cat); // cat1 is Cat
const dog1 = getValue(Dog); // dog1 is Dog

settings = [
    { key: Cat, value: Dog },
    { key: Dog, value: Cat },
]
const cat2 = getValue(Cat); // cat2 is Dog
const dog2 = getValue(Dog); // dog2 is Cat
```

That's what I mean settings could be modified in the runtime.

eg.2

```
let settings = [
    { key: Cat, value: Cat },
    { key: Dog, value: Dog },
]
// cat1 is Cat, getValue return type default as Parameter Cat
const cat1 = getValue(Cat);
// dog1 is Dog, getValue return type default as Parameter Dog
const dog1 = getValue(Dog);

settings = [
    { key: Cat, value: Dog },
    { key: Dog, value: Cat },
]
// cat2 is Dog, getValue return type is set by generic type Dog
const cat2 = getValue<Dog>(Cat);
// dog2 is Cat, getValue return type is set by generic type Cat
const dog2 = getValue<Cat>(Dog);
```

Can getValue function be implemented like this by optional generic type?

Comment: As you are using "any" the type will bee inferred rom the settings. What you mean by getValue function can not get the correct type?  const dog = getValue('dog') will give correct result why you want to typecast to Dog?

Comment: The `getValue` function is what I need, and now it is not correctly implemented. According to the `settings`, we konw `getValue('dog')` must return a `new Dog()`. But the current `getValue` function infers to `string | number | boolean | Cat | Dog`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `User`, `Cat`, and `Dog` are [structurally identical](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and therefore TypeScript treats them as the same type.  This is probably not desirable, so I will give them some differing structure:

```
class User {
    name: string;
    password: string = "hunter2";
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Dog {
    name: string;
    bark() {

    }
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Cat {
    name: string;
    meow() {

    }
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now the compiler can tell them apart.

---

My approach here would be to make `getValue()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function whose return value is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types):

```
type Settings = typeof settings[number];
type SettingsValue<K extends Settings["key"]> = Extract<Settings, { key: K }>["value"];
type InstanceIfCtor<T> = T extends new (...args: any) => infer R ? R : T;
type SettingsOutputValue<K extends Settings["key"]> = InstanceIfCtor<SettingsValue<K>>;

declare function getValue<K extends Settings["key"]>(key: K): SettingsOutputValue<K>;
```

The `Settings` type is just a union of all `{key: K, value: V}` element types in `settings`.  Then, `SettingsValue<K>` takes a `K` which is one of the `key` types of `Settings`, and returns the corresponding `value` type.

The type `InstanceIfCtor<T>` takes a type `T` and, if `T` is a constructor type, returns its corresponding instance type; otherwise it returns `T`.

And `SettingsOutputValue<K>` first gets the value type `SettingsValue<K>`, and then evaluates `InstanceIfCtor<>` of it to find the type that `getValue()` should return.  If `K` is one of the types for which `SettingsValue<K>` is not a constructor, then the return type is just `SettingsValue<K>`.  Otherwise, if `SettingsValue<K>` *is* a constructor, then `SettingsOutputValue<K>` is the instance type of that constructor.

---

Implementing `getValue()` can't really be done in a way that the compiler verifies as safe, since it can't follow the higher order reasoning needed to convert `K` into `SettingsOutputValue<K>` for an unspecified `K`.  I usually just do this as a single call-signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to loosen the type checking, keeping in mind that I need to be careful that my implementation is really doing what the call signature says it's doing:

```
function getValue<K extends Settings["key"]>(key: K): SettingsOutputValue<K>;
function getValue(key: Settings["key"]) {
    const item = settings.find(obj => obj.key === key);
    if (item) {
        const { value } = item
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            return new value('test value');
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('not found');
    }
}
```

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
const dog = getValue('dog'); // Dog
dog.bark();
const cat = getValue('cat'); // Cat
cat.meow();
const user = getValue(User); // User
user.password.toUpperCase();
```

Looks good.  The `dog`, `cat`, and `user` variables are inferred to be of type `Dog`, `Cat`, and `User`, respectively.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNH0B2YAtggFzQQAuSAlngOYDcWu0ADpBAO4D2SAJmUo160ALzQARAAsArngrIATBKbZcwbniEzgFXgAoCxQVVp0AlGmYtcFKdQgA6IwjH4iCVSwC+WX5ixQDmgAEW46KzUcFxNhRmscACMwJABrfUsMAKjofxYNLSodPSRDD1izTISbOwdnDzcXL1x-f0DwKGgAYTAKSJYY8lN6Zpxibk4MyOq89U1tXQNBoUr+mxxapxdGj1HcvyxA+b7ECgozGHEAbWrUaFSEAE8yAHIwF4AaaAA3MBAZUjQF4regvXIfW73J6vRKfH5-AFkACMigAzODIQ9nkDgHDfv9AUVXN4ITk7ljXnxwniEYCwhESZjoTjejSCWQen1GWSodj6V98Yjur0MTyKcKKALaWR6aKWOTmfBkFL2XBEChuQBdaCQaAFSiqLAUR6sVwAZQQZwubmNpu4ADNyJbzvQIFc8DJCIlkJrVLbzc6LgA1WkAHgA0tAEAAPBR4PgwC1W11XCRYiSagB8bgAorGkGBdKGky66BAvgrsZHvJnU4KEBm-SbXABJQpgPDABAt+1dEqhgAq2fEA6jsYQ8ZgeAQnGg+kcC5SZbIHcellE2do9uQ0AAStAAPx76BkAdN03QEsXADyMgorDvIYJEbHcYTl8DKbTTwzw+gbcoDsux7PteGLT8yyfAEI0zTNDUwe05F0ahNGgOhLSghAXxjN9Ewgt1v0eX99HFcNzDIK9XVve9HzDcM4KwRDO3OVD0IoTCSOZSiy1TdNNSqHJ9T6agFEINxTlLJx7VoPh9G4RIACsxGzeSFMcLExFEcQsXMPZqEdfQRIQQgBPWHAhLQeECVyNwjMIaoWH0ud-QdKyAU08QXiY5DNBeUyzJYJBLRkJA8HwGc3IQfQXgUShIr8vYfCjEBEDWAKcCCigQrC+tEpaGZktSrIArsJAJnC2ccyQMrShePBuD6e1uDkPgEpmA5sgsqkInENiOJebqEugAB6YbQnCLBuscZI0gyVQLOAEVeow2losWightGiVAl6RxxkmXSjkKaAZHVNw+tWpUkF0kaxqurBTuQRx2CgHh+EcPRYFYU0kB6RA5uYIA)

Comment: Thank you very much!  
I changed the question a litter. The `settings` is not pre-defined and could be  modified in the runtime. So we can not get any type info by `settings`.
Is there any good ideal?

Comment: It depends strongly on what you mean by "modified [at] runtime". Please consider providing a [mcve] that demonstrates such modifications; otherwise the answer could be "yes" or "no" and I can't tell which one with the information provided.

Comment: I have updated the question. Could you help me more?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not.  TypeScript's type system is not geared toward arbitrarily mutating the type of variables, which is what you're doing with `settings`.  Are you willing to use new `settings` objects and `getValue()` functions whenever you want to change the settings?  If so, you can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/lm0vxw).  But your code as stated where you modify `settings` cannot be strongly typed in the way you want.

Comment: I have updated the question again. I agree with you that typescript cannot get right type info by dynamic settings. But is there any way to get right return type by optional generic type when calling getValue function?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const settings = [
    { key: 'a', value: 'string' },
    { key: 'b', value: 123 },
    { key: 'c', value: true },
    { key: 'dog', value: Dog },
    { key: 'cat', value: Cat },
    { key: Dog, value: Cat },
    { key: Cat, value: Dog },
    { key: User, value: User },
] as const;

type SettingsKey = typeof settings[number]['key'];

function getValue(key: SettingsKey) {
    const item = settings.find(obj => obj.key === key);
    if (item) {
        const { value } = item
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            // const value: new (name: string) => User | Dog | Cat
            return new value('test value');
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error('not found');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I changed the question a litter. The settings is not pre-defined and could be modified in the runtime. So we can not get any type info by settings. Is there any good ideal?